# Multivariate normal distribution conditional on two random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am given a dataset with in each column a set of data pertaining to a different random variable. I know that the data are normally distributed. Now how can I find the estimated mean and variance of the last observation from the first random variable conditional on the last observation of the other two random variables?

I thought of finding the conditional pdf and the calculating the maximum likelihood estimator. However, I am not sure how I can condition on two random variables. Could anyone help me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The wiki article has the answer, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos That only describes how to condition on one variable, doesn't it?

Comment: No. _Before_ the sub-section "Bivariate case" it describes the conditional distribution involving arbitrary numbers of variables. The symbols are in bold, they refer to vectors-matrices. In your case $q=1$ and $N=3$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos "then, the distribution of $x_1$ conditional on $x_2 = a$ is multivariate normal $(x1|x2 = a) ~ N(μ, Σ)$" I am still not sure then how I should do this if I want to condition on *two* variables. How would that go?

Comment: It is _not_ multivariate normal anymore, since $x_1$ is only one variable, and $x_2$ is a random vector that includes your two variables. This conditional distribution is just univariate normal. Just apply the dimensions of your case to the general formulas in the article.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I'll try, thank you for your help :)!

Comment: Let me know if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. $\Sigma$ is the $3\times 3$ covariance matrix of the *joint* distribution of your three variables (just look at the article). It is then *unequally* partitioned into sub-matrices. Denoting $v_{ij}$ the elements of $\Sigma$, we have, following the notation of the article,

$$\Sigma_{11}  = v_{11}=\sigma^2_1\;,\; \Sigma_{12} = [v_{12}\;\; v_{13}]\;,\; \Sigma_{21} = \left[ \begin{matrix} v_{21}\\ \\ v_{13}\end{matrix} \right]$$ 
$$\Sigma_{22} =\left[\begin{matrix} v_{22} &v_{23} \\ v_{32} & v_{33} 
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} \sigma^2_{2} &v_{23} \\ v_{32} & \sigma^2_{3} 
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Then the conditional expectation function $E(X_1\mid X_2,X_3)$ is

$$E(X_1\mid X_2,X_3) = \mu_1 + \Sigma_{12}\Sigma^{-1}_{22}\left [\begin{matrix} X_2-\mu_2 \\ \\X_3-\mu_3\end{matrix} \right] $$

I guess now you can work the term for the conditional variance.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot for your help! I'll try it out but I think this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!